# Integer minutes/hours to Ruby Time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time

I have the following duration:

1456

14 minutes and 56 seconds
And I need to convert to time and format like this:

14:56

In case of hours:

6500

01:05

How can I do that with ruby/rails ?
I'm looking for a solution but I can't.

Comment: are you 100% sure that you will always get a string containing exactly 4 digits, with the first 2 defining the amount of minutes and the last 2 the amount of seconds?

Comment: What is `1456` – a string, an integer? Where does this data come from?

Comment: is the output another string or a `Time` object?

Comment: 1456 is a integer stored in database

Comment: That's a really odd way to store durations :-)

Answer (score 1):

Updated (considering @eiko's comment), this code will handle any (positive) integer (inferior to `60*24*100`):

```
def custom_duration_to_hours_mn_sec_str(duration)
  min, sec = duration.divmod(100)
  total_in_seconds = min.minutes + sec.seconds
  Time.at(total_in_seconds).utc.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
end
custom_duration_to_hours_mn_sec_str(56) # 56 seconds
# => "00:00:56" 
custom_duration_to_hours_mn_sec_str(1456) # 14 mn 56 seconds
# => "00:14:56"
custom_duration_to_hours_mn_sec_str(12056) # 120 mn 56 seconds
# => "02:00:56"
```

**Limitation:** if the duration is over `60*24` minutes (quantity of minutes in a 24h day), it will start again to '00:00:00' and therefore ignore the quantity of days.

```
custom_duration_to_hours_mn_sec_str(60*24*100) # *100 to add the zeros for seconds
# => "00:00:00"
```

Comment: The OP specified that the starting value is an integer. It's also reasonable to assume that the integer will often be 5 digits or greater, since even a duration of 2 hours would be 5 digits. You can easily get the minutes and seconds like so: `min, sec = duration.divmod 100`, which would account for an integer of arbitrary size.

Comment: Just like splitting the duration into `min` and `sec`, you can split `min` into hours and minutes via `hour, min = min.divmod(60)`. The three variables can then be formatted via `sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', hour, min, sec)`.